# GUI designer for managing Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, gui-designer

Is there a GUI tool using which I can design new Django models graphically? For example, drawing lines between fields in different models to indicate a foreign key.

Modifying existing models graphically would also be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[uml-to-django](http://code.google.com/p/uml-to-django/) might be of interest to you, though I can't personally vouch for it.

Answer (score 8):

Another suggestion is found in [Django Builder](http://mmcardle.github.io/django_builder/#/home), you can define a model and the builder will get all your program needs such as views, serializers, urls, tests, admins, forms, and full functional html files in an instant.

> UPDATE

There is also new version for Django Builder called [djangobuilder.io](https://djangobuilder.io/#/).

Answer (score 1):

You can import django models on [dbpatterns](http://dbpatterns.com).

Comment: unfortunately domain is gone :( dbpatterns was awesome.

Comment: Soon I will try to run the app on a different domain @vigo

Comment: would be awesome <3

Answer (score 0):

You can normally generate your models in Django and migrate them to a database and read that database with DBeaver (https://dbeaver.com) and generate the ERD to see your db desing.