# Django App Ignite

Tags: django

Is there anything like [App Ignite](http://www.appignite.com/login) for django? Like something that allows you to create django apps with a GUI?

-**OR**-

Is there a Django backend for App Ignite? or plans for one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell it will only be available in PHP, but it's in closed beta at the moment. If you want a PYTHON gui framework, you can try looking at [GuiProgramming](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming)

Edit: this might be useful: http://code.google.com/p/uml-to-django/ coming from [GUI designer for managing Django models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806681/gui-designer-for-managing-django-models)

Comment: sorry I think I wasn't clear enough... I was thinking more like a GUI app for writing django apps... I'm not trying to make a GUI application (and I don't think you can with django anyway)